# titanium android runtime error box always shows wrong line number

Tags: javascript, android, titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

i am developing an cross platform application in OSX mavericks environment with titanium sdk 3.3.
While debugging on android the runtime error caught always show [1,69] for line number.So i can't spot exact position of actual error.
The same environment run smoothly on IOS application.
Any one please suggest a solution.Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: i think you might be using **alloy**, so your code is under `app/`, but the runtime errors thrown maps to the code in `Resources` directory.

Comment: no i am using titanium signle window application

Comment: This might be because the TiStudio minifies the code written and hence there will be only one line of code in the resultant files. Try to use exception handlers in the code

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am concerned android errors show the line of code in the final "java binary" file and not the actual line in your Titanium source code.

Maybe you should report this as a bug report to the Appcelerator team.

Answer (score 0):

The Android environment appears to be less forgiving than the IOS environment when working with Titanium.  Often, after I've written my app to work for IOS, I then need to fix it to work on Android.  On the positive side, these always appear to be actual errors that I guess the IOS environment either assists with or doesn't find critical enough to stop the program execution.  When I fix the code to work for Andriod, it almost always works for IOS as well with the need for branching.

Just because your code is working on IOS doesn't mean you don't have a bug in it.  I find that the Android debugging process helps me strengthen the quality of my app as a whole.  Don't ignore the error on the Android side at [1,69], there is likely an issue there.  Perhaps an unassigned variable or a null object.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium studio most of the time won't show us the exact line number in our code. This holds for both iOS and Android. Other commenters have shared their thoughts about the reasons behind. I accepted that this is the price I have to pay for close to native experience. (at least for now)

The best solution I found to work like this, is to learn how to use the debugger in Titanium studio. You can add the Debug Perspective in the upper right corner with the Open perspective button. This will give you a Studio layout tuned for debugging. I use this view to fix complex problems.